# Problemas con ng serve en nuevo proyecto Angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Luego de Instalar la última versión de Angular y la versión 16.13.1 de node, he creado un proyecto en Angular. Al abrir la carpeta en el VSC y luego de escribir ng serve en la terminal, me saltan varios errores. Alguien sabe a qué se debe y cómo solucionarlo? Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si aún te sirva, pero el orden debería ser así luego de instalar angular desde la terminal del IDE.

```
cd ./nombredelproyecto      <<te ubicas en la carpeta destino>>

ng serve    <<inicializa server>>
```

Answer (score 0):

me paso exactamente el mismo problema!, debe ser un error en el link "SRC" cuando enlazaste la opcion al angular.json (o similares), creeme, es un error tan estupido que nadie se da cuenta a la primera pero es tan sencillo de solucionar como arreglar el error en el Path